# Protected sending/receiving data via HTTP

Tags: iphone

This a pretty basic question. Let's say I have this iPhone/iPad app that, at some point, gives the user the option to login. The username/pw are stored on the server's database.

What is the best way to communicate with the server to check if the username/pw are correct. How can I safely send & receive these requests via HTTP (without sending the plain pw)? What encryption/decryption should I use (both in-app and serverside)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use SSL (i.e. https). Whatever you do, don't roll your own crypto!

Comment: Oke thanks for pointing that out. I'm not very well known with SSL/HTTPS. How do I implement something like that? Is it much work? Do you know some article that should get me started?

Comment: If you just change the URL you talk to from `http://whatever` to `https://whatever` then it should all work like magic...but things may be different on an iPhone or iPad. You'll need to set up a server certificate - check your web server documentation for how to do that.

Comment: From my experience, in order to use SSL on the iPad, you need a certificate and cannot use a self-issued one. When we tried a self-issued, it dropped the connection.

Comment: My host says this about SSL on their FAQ page: "By entering a URL such as https://www.ssl-id.net/yourstratodomain.eu the contents of the Web space are coded and then transferred (in place of "yourstratodomain.eu" use your own domain name).". I've tried this, made a connection (in iPhone app) and it worked (i've send some data and got a response). Can I now assume that I'm using SSL (https in this case) properly?

Comment: As long as it has the `https://` prefix rather than `http://` then you're OK. By the way, I'd suggest that you read up on how to securely store passwords (salt + iterated hash). There are a number of questions about it on stackoverflow, or read http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html for a good overview of how to do it properly.

Comment: Yes, sounds like it. Your hosting company probably has a valid certificate on ssl-id.net, so anything passed through it passes inspection.

Answer (score -1):

if you dont want to send the password plain text,
you should use md5 hash (there is built in function in iphone)
encrypt the password with md5 function and send it to the server.

if the server DB has the password in plain text, he can also make md5 hash
and compare it with the one he received from the client.

you can also use this method to encrypt you're username.

Comment: This is wrong for so many reasons. MD5 is broken; **never** store passwords in plain text; hashing is not encryption; "you're" should be "your".